# How to get extract words from differents lines in file and combine them to another file

Tags: bash

If I have a file or output:

```
givenName: filip
gidNumber: 500
homeDirectory: /home/users/ffilip
sn: filip
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
userPassword:: MTIz

givenName: stiv
gidNumber: 500
homeDirectory: /home/users/stiv
sn: stiv
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
userPassword:: BhJk
```

I want to get:

```
givenName: filip, userPassword:: MTIz 

givenName: stiv, userPassword:: BhJk
```

Comment: This looks like ldap, you can just query with ldapsearch for example only the stuff you need.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:
assuming you have the `output` in a file:

```
cat output| egrep "givenName:|userPassword::"|paste -d ", "  - -
```

or

```
ldap command|egrep "givenName:|userPassword::"|paste -d ", "  - -
```

or to have the separation `comma` with an additional `space` you can use:

```
ldap command|egrep "givenName:|userPassword::"|paste -d ", "  - -|sed 's/,/, /g'
```

Of course you can also accomplish this with `awk`:

```
a bit modified to use a delimiter with only 1 space:
ldap command|awk '$1=="givenName:" {printf "%s", $0} $1=="userPassword::" {print ",", $0}'
```

or Perl's regex functionality.. as the other answers suggest.

Comment: I assume that `paste` does not support separators with more than one character.

Comment: well you can append `|sed 's/,/, /g'` to the commands.. to accomplish that

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `awk`. Simply matching the first field and outputting the record without a newline when it is `"givenName:"` and then concatenating a `", "` and outputting the `"userPassword::"` record with a newline, e.g.

```
awk '$1=="givenName:" {printf "%s", $0} $1=="userPassword::" {print ", ", $0}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your output in the file named `output` you would have:

```
$ awk '$1=="givenName:" {printf "%s", $0} $1=="userPassword::" {print ", ", $0}' output
givenName: filip,  userPassword:: MTIz
givenName: stiv,  userPassword:: BhJk
```

(if you want a space between the lines you can output an additional newline after the `userPassword::` or before `givenName:`. You can set a flag to prevent an additional newline before the first record. Up to you)

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -n '/^givenName:/h;/^userPassword:/{H;g;s/\n/, /p;}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `ed`(1).

```
printf '%s\n' 'v/^givenName:\|^userPassword::/d' 'g/.\{1,\}/;+1j' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```